# EF7 Add-Migration throws exceptions in .net 4.6 data access project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have a .net 4.6 solution with 1 asp.net mvc 5 (asp.net 4.5) project and one data access library. This is a database first project. Yet I want from now on to use migrations and code-first approach.
I run Enable-Migrations in console, it says

> Enable-Migrations is obsolete. Use Add-Migration to start using Migrations.

Ok, so I type in my console

> Add-Migration -Name first

And console throws an error

```
PM> Add-Migration -Name first
Add-Migration : Exception calling "CreateDomain" with "3" argument(s):
"The type initializer for 'System.Net.ServicePointManager' threw an
exception."
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-Migration -Name first
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-Migration],
MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeInitializationException,Add-Migration

PM>
```

Comment: Have you tried building your solution in 4.5?

Comment: Pls show your DbContext and Startup code

Comment: No, I haven't tried building it for net4.5. Not sure why should it change anything. There is no startup. It is old-fashioned ASP.Net 4.5 web app.

Comment: Try running the `use-dbcontext YourContextHere` command first. If that doesn't work, try the `add-migration` command *without* the `-name` option (but leave `first` in the command, i.e. `add-migration first`).

Comment: use-dbcontext MyContextName gave me same error Exception calling "CreateDomain" with "3" argument(s).   And same error when I try 'add-migration first'

Comment: Try `Add-Migration first`

Comment: I wrote in my comment above. I did try it. Same result. Add-Migration : Exception calling "CreateDomain" with "3" argument(s) ...

Comment: This could be a bug. Bugs on EF7 can be filed here https://github.com/aspnet/entityframework/issues. Please follow instructions from https://github.com/aspnet/Home/blob/dev/CONTRIBUTING.md#filing-issues